# Is it rude to request multiple signatures at a gamebook signing event?

Tags: social

Later on this week I'll be attending a book signing event with the author of the Lone Wolf game book series Joe Dever. The event coincides with the publication (whether entirely new or simply refurbished I'm unsure) of the first book in the series translated into Swedish.
Being inexperienced with book signings and never having been one for collecting autographs, I would assume the new publication is sold on the spot and signed by Joe shortly thereafter. I believe it to be a smaller event, with an expected head-count of below 30 participants (pretty impressive for a book-series originally conjured in the eighties!).

While a fan myself, having played through Lone Wolf books on several occasions, I'm considering giving the signed copy of the new publication to one of my two siblings; neither have ever been introduced to single-player gamebooks. In the best of worlds, of course, I'd be able to gift a signed copy to the both of them, which brings me to the subject of my question:

**Might it be considered rude to purchase two copies at the signing event and ask for both of them to be signed for this purpose?**

I'm thinking this is a good place to ask, since I can imagine authors of game- and roleplaying books having a more intimate relationship with their (possibly smaller) fanbase, compared to more mainstream authors and public figures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about social protocol that is not specific to the RPG community.

Comment: I think it is different in an RPG context.  It's rude for the Stephen King signing line, no one cares for an RPG signing. There are no RPG authors so popular that their signing lines would be overly prohibitive. The question is scoped down to RPGs and that ecosystem is different enough that the question stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience from going to a few cons authors are generally happy to sign whatever you want them to, especially for smaller gatherings like the one you are going to. If it were something larger they might not want to just so they could give more people time to see them, but with only 30 people I don't think you will have much trouble. If you want to find out for sure you could try contacting the venue and ask if there was a limit on how many items you could have signed, or when you get there ask the author if you could get 2 copies signed to give as gifts.